# Adding Multiple Handlers to Logger

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I'm using java.util.logging. In my code, I'm adding multiple handlers to my logger. I have 1 ConsoleHandler and 1 FileHandler. I only want levels above Info (inclusive) to be printed to the console and all levels to be printed to the log file. When I try to set the logging levels of the 2 file handlers accordingly, and add the handlers to the logger, the log file ends up only including levels above Info (as specified by the ConsoleHandler). Does this mean I cannot specify two different file handlers for one logger? How can I resolve this issue and get the desired functionality? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: In general, you can register multiple handlers with each Logger object, according to [this "Thinking in Java" chapter](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ317_016.htm). My guess is that you probably define log levels incorrectly. Add your code snippet to the question to let us see the way you're doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question myself. You need to set the level of the logger to Level.FINEST before adding the handlers to it because the logger by default is set to a level higher than FINEST. Therefore setting the ConsoleHandler's level to FINEST without changing the level of the logger will not produce the required results.